# Data.List.iterate lazy evaluation not happening

Tags: haskell

I'm having the above function, but when I call it, it gets stuck, the Data.List.iterate evaluates without stopping.

```
rp:: RandomGen g => g -> ([Int], g)
rp g = (map (\x -> (last (fst x))) lst , snd (next g))
    where 
        lst = (Data.List.iterate id ([1], g_second))
        (g_first, g_second) = (split g)
```

Why does that happend?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `rp` supposed to do? If it is supposed to make a random list, you should probably pass in the desired length of the random list...

Comment: It suppose to end first of all. Isn't it?

Comment: The first argument in your tuple is the infinite list `[1..]` hence my question about the length.

Comment: I'm using it with takeWhile, but I'm sure that the stopping condition is good

Comment: The first component is the infinite list `[1,1,1,1,...]` so `takeWhile` takes nothing or all of it.

Comment: By the way, `iterate id` is a bit unidiomatic: if you really want to repeat the same element `x` forever, use `repeat x`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve with your function, the reason it doesn't stop is because you're mapping over an infinite list and giving it no reason *to* stop.

The infinite list originates in your use of `iterate`:

> `lst = (Data.List.iterate id ([1], g_second))`

What you've done there is create an infinite list which contains an infinite number of the tuple value `([1], g_second)`. That seems like a logic error - that list of tuple has no variation; every element is the same, to infinity. To be clear, this list you are building looks like this:

```haskell
[([1], g_second), ([1], g_second), ([1], g_second), ([1], g_second)...]
```

`g_second` is unchanging and never gets a reason to evaluate, so it is, in essence, discarded.

If you were to use something like `take` or `takeWhile`, you could force that infinite list to stop and return a known number of elements. However, by using `map` in this statement:

```haskell
map (\x -> (last (fst x))) lst
```

All you are doing is pulling the value `1` out of the tuple and repeating it forever.

And since you discard `g_second` and never use `g_first`, your function is equivalent to the following:

```haskell
rp :: RandomGen g => g -> ([Int], g)
rp g = (repeat 1 , snd (next g))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to generate an infinite list of random-numbers based on a `RandomGen g` then you can use `Data.List.unfold` as it fit's `next` nicely:

```
> import System.Random
> import Data.List
> let rnds g = unfoldr (Just . next) g
> let rnds' = rnds (mkStdGen 0)
> take 3 rnds'
[2147482884,2092764894,1390461064]
```

BTW: **yes** the final `g` is missing - but to get this you would have to generate the infinite list first ... which seems unlikely (*plus* it would not fit `unfoldr` as nicely ;))